# Expected primary-expression before ':' token expected `;' before ':' token

Tags: c++

Учусь по книжкам языку С++.

Собственно простейшая программа:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned short int Width = 5;
    int Length = 10;

    unsigned short int Area = Width * Length;

    std::cout << "Width: "  << Width  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Length: " << Length << std:endl;
    std::cout << "Area "    << Area   << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

На Dev-C++ выдает:

> expected primary-expression before ':' token. 
> expected `;' before ':' token

Помогите, подскажите в чем проблема, где ошибка?

Comment: Огромное спасибо всем участникам, проблема решена. Спасибо за содействие.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Видимо здесь `std:endl;` там должно быть два двоеточия.

Comment: А как рекомендуется: указывать using namespace std или как автор вопроса везде вставлять std:: ?

Comment: @BuilderC Можно использовать компромиссный вариант — `using namespace std`, но в пределах `int main(...)`.

Comment: разные люди рекомендуют по разному. Я за явное указание. Использование `using namespace` иногда приводит к трудновылавливаемым багам (особенно, если в начинают совпадать имена функций).